# Suggestions on to make my compressor faster

Tags: arrays, performance, compression, byte

I have some data which I'm compressing with a custom compressor, the compressed data is fine but the compressor takes ages, and I'm seeking advice on how I could make that faster. Let me give you all the details.

The input data is an array of bytes, maximum 2^16 of them. Since those bytes in the array NEVER assume values between 0x08 and 0x37 (inclusive), I decided that I could exploit that for a simple LZ-like compression scheme that works by replacing any found sequence of 4 to 51 bytes in length that is already been found at a "lower address" (I mean closer to the array's beginning) with a single byte in the 0x08 to 0x37 range that would then be followed by two bytes addressing the low and high byte of the index of the beginning of the sequence, thus giving the decompressor the length (within that single byte) and address of the original data, to rebuild the original array.

The compressor works this way: for any sequence of any length from 51 to 4 bytes (I test longer sequences first) starting from any index (from left to right) I check if there's a correspondence 'left' of that, which means at an index which is *lower* than the starting point I'm checking. In case there is more than a single match, I choose the match that 'saves' more, which means the longer correspondence starting at the leftmost place.

The results are just **perfect**... but of course this is over-killing - it's **4** nested 'for' cycles with a memcmp() inside that, and it takes **minutes** on a modern workstation to compress some 20 KB worth of data, and that's why I'm seeking help.

Code is accessible [here](https://github.com/sverx/PSGlib/blob/master/tools/src/psgcomp.c), if you need to sneak a peek. The 'job' starts at line 44.

Of course I can give you any detail you need, there's nothing secret here (BTW, just in case... I'm not going to change compression scheme for this reason, as this one works exactly as I need it!)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really obvious one is that you don't have to loop over the lengths, just find out what the longest match at that position is. That's not a "search", just keep extending the match by 1 for every matching pair of characters. When it stops, you have the longest match at that position (naturally you can force it to stop at 51 too, so it doesn't overrun).

An other typical trick is keeping a hashmap that maps keys of 3 or 4 characters to a list of offsets where they can be found. That way you only need to try positions that have some hope of resulting in a match. This is also described in the [DEFLATE RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) all the way at the bottom.

Comment: good suggestions - it'll take me a few days to understand if/how can I apply them...

Comment: @sverx good luck. By the way you may want to implement their idea of "lazy matching" too, not for speed but compression factor.

Comment: I was wondering if there's a standard function that tests two byte buffers and returns how many bytes match. I mean, of course I might roll my own but maybe I'm just reinventing the wheel... any hint?

Comment: I don't think there is one, but I'm not a C expert

Comment: I went from a compression that took a few minutes to one that took just some seconds just avoiding to loop over the lengths - and I'm fine with the way it is. So thank you! :)